# 2D String Array Bubble Sort

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to bubble sort a 2D string array. I am currently stuck trying to figure out why my program isnt sorting the strings. I spsupect it could be possible that something is wrong with void swap. I feel somehting with the 2D array needs to be put in there. I am not very sure I just learned how to create bubble sorting algorithms.

#include

```
using namespace std;

  const int SIZE = 2;
  const int ROWS = 2;

void bubbleSort(string values[][SIZE]);
void swap(int &, int &);

int main ()

{



    string values[ROWS][SIZE] = {{"A23", "A12"}, {"name1", "name2"}};

    cout << "Unsorted Values: " << endl;


    for(auto element : values)
        cout << element << " ";

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Sorted Values" << endl;

         bubbleSort(values);
            for (auto element:values)

        cout << element << " ";

    return 0;

}

void bubbleSort(string values[][SIZE])
{
    int maxElement;
    int index;

    for (maxElement = SIZE - 1; maxElement > 0; maxElement--)
    {
        for( index = 0; index < maxElement; index++)
        {
            if (values[0][index] > values[0][index + 1])
            {
                swap(values[0][index], values[0][index + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: The program is currently outputting the memory location. Example: Unsorted Values:
0x6dfe6c 0x6dfe9c
Sorted Values
0x6dfe6c 0x6dfe9c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program prints out the adresses because your print loop iterate each entry of your string 2D array. Consequently, every entry is an array. So `arr` holds the pointer to the first element of the array. 
You only need a nested loop to print out the values of the single elements:

```
for (auto row : values)
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        std::cout << row[i] << " ";
```

Furthermore, there is no need to implement an own swap function. Just use `std::swap(T&,T&)`

But i assume that you want to achieve a multi array sort. Then you should use a simple struct to represent an entity instead of multiple arrays and implement a operator to compare two entities. I suggest to use a range based container too. Then you can take advantage of the standard sort functions.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Entry
{
    string id;
    string name;

    bool operator<(const Entry& comp)
    {
        return id < comp.id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto print = [](const vector<Entry>& vec)
    {
        for (auto& el : vec)
        {
            cout << el.id << "->" << el.name << "\t";
        }   
    };


    vector<Entry> values { {"A23","name1" }, {"A12", "name2"} };

    cout << "Unsorted Values: " << endl;
    print(values);
    cout << endl;

    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
    cout << "Sorted Values" << endl;
    print(values);


    return 0;
}
```

Prints out:

```
Unsorted Values:
A23->name1   A12->name2
Sorted Values:
A12->name2   A23->name1
```